# How to reference nested scss class within media query?

Tags: sass, nested, media-queries

I have `media query` used in scss class, I would like to create media query and define all scss class in that media query. I have trouble accessing nested scss class in media query.
Here is my code

```
.data-one {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  &.mobile {
    width: 100%;
    .data {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }

  .data {
    height: 72px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    max-width: 224px;
    // @media (max-width: layout-breakpoint-tablet-start) {  -----------> This is the original code 
    //   display: none;
    // }
  }
}
```

This is what I have tried but it is not working as expected

```
@media (max-width: layout-breakpoint-tablet-start) {
  .data-one {
    +.data {
      display: none;
      }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sass 3.2](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/sasss-content-directive) added the `@content` directive, which allows us to pass a content block into a mixin as following:

```css
 @mixin screen($size) {
  $desktop: "(min-width: 1024px)";
  $tablet: "(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)";
  $mobile: "(max-width: 767px)";
  @if $size == desktop {
    @media only screen and #{$desktop} {
      @content;
    }
  }
  @else if $size == tablet {
    @media only screen and #{$tablet} {
      @content;
    }
  }
  @else if $size == mobile {
    @media only screen and #{$mobile} {
      @content;
    }
  }
  @else {
    @media only screen and #{$size} {
      @content;
    }
  }
}


.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  @include screen('tablet') {
    width: 90%;
  }

  @include screen('desktop') {
    width: 85%;
  }
}
```

If you have any question about it feel free to ask.